# Best way to implement this flow in C#

Tags: c#, coding-style

I need to make an application that has 22 Primary images, and 13 secondary images.

Description of the flow: I see image1, have one checklist with two options (these are the conditions). If checked condition1 then it goes to image23, then if option2 checked  goes to image 24 and then to image2, if both not checked goes directly to image2.

Here is a flow to exemplify:

[image: a flowchart]

In some cases may have two conditions or three or even only one condition.

I need a away of doing this in C#. How can i jump between images ? 35 Panels playing with Visible option ? MultiViews ? Any other control ?
Is there any way better for doing this without so many ifs elses ? Please give me some guidelines..

Comment: There is always the use of `case` for when you have more than one option. But for a boolean This or that, `if` `else` is best

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? User customizable? Design pattern?

Comment: First of all, the best way of jumping from image to image in UI. Panels Visible true/false ? Multiview ?

Comment: second the best design pattern, because i think i will have so many states

Comment: Create one Panel, set a binding to an Image property and then change the Image as you need it. No need to create multiple panels and switch visibilities.

Answer (score 2):

nope just use if/else if/else or case statements...

personally I don't think that there is a "perfect" way to implement such thing..

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about finite state machines; you could pretty easily roll your own state machine once you have a good grasp on the theory.

You could store the transitions between states in a file for maximum ease of configuration, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps or not but it seems that an "empty" condition for Image3 or Image4 is equivalent to a nonempty condition, `true`.

This means that you have a mapping between conditions and values. You can use it to extract this part of the code to a method which takes the condition (or just `true` as an empty condition) and an image name and does something with the name if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on Design Patterns. Rather than the less than useful "gang of 4" book, I suggest the quite excellent book, [Head First Design Patterns](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/), by Eric Freeman and Elisabeth Freeman.

[image: Head First Design Patterns Cover]

The particular pattern you're interested in is the State Pattern. This is a class diagram

[image: State Pattern Class Diagram]

In a nutshell, you have a *context* that does something useful. It's external interface is entirely dependent on your needs. Each *context* instance has a number of different internal states it might be in. Coding this as a bunch of nested if/then/else/switch/lookup, etc. gets complicated and makes maintenance and debugging difficult. So...

You create a single abstract type representing the state for the context. Each concrete subtype of that abstract *state* class is a different state and implements the behaviours required for that state.

Your *context* has a single internal member referencing its current state that gets initialized with the start state.

One of the responsibilities for the concrete _state instances is to provide the *context* with the next *state* it should transition to based on the action(s) taken.

Normally, a *state* doesn't have any members of its own, save a reference to the context. It simply provides behavior. It helps if it has access to the internals of the context, however you choose to do that.

The State Pattern is similar to (but different from) the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html).

Here's some links to get you started.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern
- http://www.jamessugrue.ie/design/design-patterns-uncovered-the-state-pattern
- http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/04/30/the-state-pattern-an-underappreciated-pattern/
- http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc433-0101/Lectures/designPatterns2.pdf